# "Run in Unsafe Mode" is not applied in Safari

Tags: macos, java, safari, java-web-start

I'm currently developing a Java-application, which is deployed via Java Web Start. Because this application needs access to the file system, the Java-plugin must be configured in Safari to "Run in Unsafe Mode" (cfr. [instructions here](http://fed4fire-testbeds.ilabt.iminds.be/jfed-documentation/mac.html#changing-safari-security-setting-safari-only)). This works fine on most systems, but on one particular system this setting won't change: after selecting the option in the Menu, and confirming that I trust the website, the dropdown-box stays fixed at "Ask".

What can I do to solve this problem? The system is running an up-to-date version of OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.